# Android: How to read assets from another thread in C++

Tags: android, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface, assets

I'm writing code in C++ for Android. The main code is written in Java, but I would like to start another thread invoked from JNI call and access assets from C++. However, when I pass `AAssetsManager` from `getAssets()`, it works only within scope of JNI function call. When other thread tries to use, I get an invalid pointer. I also made sure that the object `AAssetsManager` is not garbage collected by writing it to a static variable. Do you have any advice on how I could make it work?

In other works, I would like to access `AAssetManager` and cache in other object.

Thanks

Comment: Start here: http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to protect the assetManager object from GC. You need a global reference:

```
gAssetManager = env->NewGlobalRef(assetManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna access Java VM by native thread, you have to call `AttachCurrentThread()` to attach native thread to VM. Have you made this? If not, you can refer to Oracle's [JNI docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp1060).